# RestKit: What do I use now that `postObject mapResponseWith: delegate:` is deprecated?

Tags: ios, restkit

I was using this method to POST my objects, but it's been deprecated:

```
- (void)postObject:(id<NSObject>)object mapResponseWith:(RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping delegate:(id<RKObjectLoaderDelegate>)delegate
```

What should I now use instead?  How do I configure the RKObjectMapping of my response?

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted my question.  Seems like a good question to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector has been deprecated in favor of `- (void)postObject:(id<NSObject>)object usingBlock:(RKObjectLoaderBlock)block` - thus you use the block to configure a `RKObjectLoader` instance. Example follows how to set an objectMapping (mapping used to map the *response*) in the block:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:object
                                      block:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) { 
                                         loader.objectMapping = objectMapping;
                                         loader.delegate = delegate;
}];
```

Comment: Hi @mja.  Thanks for the response.  This looks like it will work, but I am blocked by another issue that I'm having creating the object.  Perhaps you could take a look? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309672/restkit-0-10-1-how-do-i-create-a-new-instance-of-an-nsmanagedobject-subclass)

Comment: I was able to fix the other issue myself. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309672/restkit-0-10-1-how-do-i-create-a-new-instance-of-an-nsmanagedobject-subclass)

Comment: Yep, this works great.  BTW, for those people who also want to set the delegate, it can be done in the block with `loader.delegate = yourDelegate`.

Comment: Yes, i missed the delegate assignment. Thanks for pointing that one out - i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:(id<NSObject>)object delegate:(id<RKObjectLoaderDelegate>)delegate];
```

This is not deprecated

Comment: How would I configure the response mapping?

Comment: [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:(RKObjectMappingDefinition *)objectOrDynamicMapping forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath];

Comment: but if you want to perform an arbitrary mapping, this approach would not work.