# RestKit 0.10.1: How do I create a new instance of an NSManagedObject subclass?

Tags: ios, restkit

I need to create a new instance of an NSManagedObject subclass, which I then intend to POST using

```
- (void)postObject:(id<NSObject>)object usingBlock:(RKObjectLoaderBlock)block
```

How do I create the object?  Do I use this method?:

`+ (id)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;`

If I am supposed to use `insertNewObjectForEntityName`, how do I get `context`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

Say that my NSManagedObject subclass was named Blah.  I can create an instance of Blah like this:

```
Blah *blah = [Blah object];
```